# Cannot login to Vtiger api with Node.js

Tags: node.js, http, vtiger

I'm trying to get a session token to access Vtiger's REST api.

I first get the challenge token using my username:

```
var USERNAME = "Josh";
var ACCESS_KEY = "DZsAkVoTeoajNCRD";
var DEFAULT_PATH = "/crm/webservice.php?";
var DEFAULT_HEADERS = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept-Charset": "utf-8"
};

var getChallenge = function( callback ) {

    var path = getPath("operation=getchallenge&username="+USERNAME);
    var reqOptions = {
              host: HOST,
              path: path,
              headers: DEFAULT_HEADERS,
              method: "get",
              rejectUnauthorized: false
    };

    request( reqOptions, function( err, result ) {
        if( err ) callback( err );
        else {
            if( !result.success ) {
                callback( new Error("Unable to generate session token") );
                return;
            }

            callback( undefined, result.result.token );
        }
    });
};
```

and that returns successfully with:

```
{ success: true,
  result: 
   { token: '5361062e11cd6',
     serverTime: 1398867502,
     expireTime: 1398867802 } }
```

Using that token I try to login:

```
var login = function( callback ) {
    getChallenge( function( err, token ) {
        if(err) callback( err );
        else {
            var hashedKey = mcrypto.MD5(token+ACCESS_KEY).toString(mcrypto.enc.Hex);
            //var hashedKey = mcrypto.createHash("md5").update(token+ACCESS_KEY).digest("hex");
            var path = getPath("operation=login&username="+USERNAME+"&accessKey="+hashedKey);
            var reqOptions = {
                      host: HOST,
                      path: path,
                      headers: DEFAULT_HEADERS,
                      method: "post",
                      rejectUnauthorized: false
            };

            request( reqOptions, function( err, result ) {
                if(err) callback( err );
                else {
                    callback(undefined, result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

but it keeps failing:

```
{ success: false,
  error: 
   { code: 'INVALID_AUTH_TOKEN',
     message: 'Specified token is invalid or expired' } }
```

I know I'm using the right vtiger server url and proper username because the first request is successful and I know my accessKey is good so what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Node.js, would it work if you use [Crypto](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.18/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto) module?

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var token = 'your-token-from-getChallenge';
var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(token+ACCESS_KEY).digest('hex');
```

Answer (score 0):

As I find the solution for the same as following

Please use **formData** key instead of **path** for request options

```
 var crypto = require('crypto');   
 var login = function( callback ) {
        getChallenge( function( err, token ) {
            if(err) callback( err );
            else {                
               var hashedKey = crypto.createHash("md5").update(token+ACCESS_KEY).digest("hex");
                var formdata= {"operation": "login", "username": USERNAME, "accessKey": hashedKey}
                var reqOptions = {
                          host: HOST,
                          formData: formdata,
                          headers: DEFAULT_HEADERS,
                          method: "post",
                          json: true
                };

                request( reqOptions, function( err, result ) {
                    if(err) callback( err );
                    else {
                        callback(undefined, result);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

As this is working for me

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but i had the same issue as OP , and after looking on the web, i found and other solution to this issue, that was related to the HEADERS of the post request. Using axios, my code look like this :

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
const axios = require('axios');

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('foo', 'bar');
const res = await axios.post('<YOUR_POST_URL>', formData, {
  // You need to use `getHeaders()` in Node.js because Axios doesn't
  // automatically set the multipart form boundary in Node.
  headers: formData.getHeaders()
});
```

After that, my node application works perfectly and i can get my sessionName from Vtiger !